# How do you delete a live binding in Firemonkey Desktop in XE6?

Tags: delphi, livebindings

I have a live binding here from an Edit control to a SpinBox control.

Selecting it and pressing the Delete key on the keyboard has no effect.  Neither do Ctrl+X, or the Edit -> Cut or Edit -> Delete menu items.

How do I remove it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the link and click "Remove link".  Maybe some day, deleting a link will work in a more intuitive manner.

[image]